# Webscraping Data Table from Sports Website using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to webscrape the competition table from following page

https://www.nrl.com/ladder/?competition=111&round=27&season=2023

I have used the following but returns a NULL result

```
url <- paste0("https://www.nrl.com/ladder/?competition=111&round=27&season=2023")

page <- read_html(url) 
contentnodes <-page %>% html_nodes ("div.vue-ladder") %>% 
      html_attr("q-data") %>% jsonlite::fromJSON()
```

Could someone show me what I am missing please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

With `httr2`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

"https://www.nrl.com/ladder//data?competition=111&round=27&season=2023" %>%  
  request() %>%  
  req_perform() %>%  
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE) %>%  
  pluck("positions")  %>%  
  as_tibble() %>% 
  unnest(everything())
```

Comment: Thank you @Hoel! May I ask how do you know what to put in the pluck() argument please? in this case its "positions" but I'd like to learn for future webscraping endeavours

Comment: @gimmethedata123 If you run the preceding code with `%>% glimpse()`, you will see how the data is structured. I simply look for the element that contains the relevant data and `pluck()` the one that you probably needed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks it is just the matter of selecting the correct div node.

Try this:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://nrl.com/ladder/competition=111&round=27&season=2023"
#read page
page <- read_html(url)

#obtain the body and convert from json
table_data <-page %>% html_elements("div.ladder-container")%>%
   html_attr("q-data") %>% 
   jsonlite::fromJSON()

table_data$position
```

Comment: Sorry I realised that while the URL was correct in my post, the URL in the sample code was not the right one, it was actually https://www.nrl.com/ladder/?competition=111&round=27&season=2023 (I've now edited the post). How would this table be extracted now?

Comment: This was the code I tried url <- paste0("https://www.nrl.com/draw/data?competition=111&round=",27,"&season=2023")  

page <- read_html(url)

contentnodes <-page %>% html_nodes ("div.vue-ladder") %>% 
  html_attr("q-data") %>% jsonlite::fromJSON()

Answer (score 0):

Using the CRAN [rjsoncons](https://mtmorgan.github.io/rjsoncons) package, I did

```
"https://www.nrl.com/ladder//data?competition=111&round=27&season=2023" |>  
  request() |>
  req_perform() |>  
  resp_body_string() |>
  j_pivot("positions", as = "tibble")
```

The string returned by `resp_body_string()` is a JSON description; I explored it with `listviewer::jsonedit()`, which opens a browser window with a widget for expanding / collapsing nodes. The `"positions"` argument to `j_pivot()` is actually a [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org) expression, and these allow quite flexible querying and transformation of JSON.